# How to send transaction in Bitcoin-Qt without transaction fee

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, transaction-fees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to not pay the transaction fees when using the standard Bitcoin client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7161/is-there-a-way-to-not-pay-the-transaction-fees-when-using-the-standard-bitcoin-c)

How do I override the transaction fee in bitcoin-qt?

Comment: No it is not possible, not with the standard bitcoin client. See this http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7161/is-there-a-way-to-not-pay-the-transaction-fees-when-using-the-standard-bitcoin-c/7170#7170

Comment: Um, yes it is possible - its really easy. There is an option in the settings you can change. See my answer in the question Gopoi referenced.