# Why isn't my transaction going through?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, dust, non-standard-transaction

I'm using `kryptokit` to send my funds. I sent [a transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/0a61ed3958e485be729ae87557291b5e992a83943f82c9884d0814e4d148e333) at about 10pm last night and here it is 10+ hrs later still unconfirmed. Is there a way to cancel it that's easy?

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction is non-standard because one output is only `379 satoshi`, and therefore below the [dust threshold](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/41082/5406) of `546 satoshi`. Most nodes don't relay non-standard transactions, and most mining pools do not include them in blocks.

You might want to consider recreating the transaction and folding this sixth of a dollar cent into the transaction fee instead. In the essence, you'd create a doublespend spending the same inputs but redeclaring the outputs. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how you would be doing that with `kryptokit`.

The easiest would probably be to import the originating address to another wallet and send a new transaction with that.

Comment: Will the transaction time out and come back to my wallet.If not what software do I need or whatever to recreate another transaction

Comment: @John: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `kryptokit`. You could import the address to another Bitcoin wallet though, and try to send it from there again.

Comment: Yea but where im getting a hang up is finding out what the key is.IDK what to do so I wrote support a email.Thx for the help though

Comment: actually I thik i got the double spend right.Wait and see I guess

Comment: https://blockchain.info/tx/ae0292c4127e68472fc5dfb5a195dfbef8393ce28dd4ff8546fc7fc053b6c1a8

Comment: @John: Great. :)