# Where can I find the current fee level for LTC?

Tags: transaction-fees, litecoin, blockspace-market

I'm currently working on something that needs to estimate the fee for Litecoin transactions. Where can I find an overview of the Litecoin fee market?

The Litecoin wiki on [Fees](https://litecoin.info/Transaction_fees) has been last updated in Nov 2015.
The Litecoin client used to specify a flat fee rate of 100,000 litoshi/kB until about two weeks ago, which appears to have been replaced with a dust limit of 100,000, and a new [default minimum of 1,000 for block inclusion](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master/src/policy/policy.h#L24).

Is there an overview where I can learn how fees work today in Litecoin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Litecoin coming from Bitcoin, most blocks have plenty of space: [right now most are between 2 and 30 transactions only](https://ltc.blockr.io/block/list/). It turns out, that most transactions appear to only pay the default [minRelayTxFee](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/48235/5406), which is currently set to 100,000 litoshi per kilobyte in the [master branch of Litecoin](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master/src/main.h#L51).

---

Update: There are some changes in the Litecoin fee structures outlined in this blog post: [Understanding Default Minimum Fees](https://medium.com/the-litecoin-school-of-crypto/understanding-minimum-fees-525877ac8f5f). In summary, the recent Litecoin Core 0.15.1 release lowers the minRelayTxFee to 1,000 litoshi per kilobyte and the minFeeRate to 10,000. Eventually, the latter is supposed to be dropped to 1,000 litoshi per kilobyte as well.