# Transaction with 0.0002 BTC fee but not confirmed sice 2 days

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, confirmations, unconfirmed-transactions, zero-confirmation

I'm a Bitcoin noob.
This is my second Bitcoin transaction and I'm getting very nervous.

My wallet (KryptoKit on Chrome) doesn't have a possibility to change the fees or anything on transactions.

Could anyone say what happens to my transaction (~100 USD) if no miner confirms it for some reason?
Now the transaction is unconfirmed since 48+ hours.

Here you can see the transaction:
https://blockchain.info/tx/2362971d010c0d38e51019139a4ebee899d0861af3d5288fae6494bad5ecd3d2

Many thanks in advance

Edit:

This is a very weird situation. At the same moment I posted this question, the related transaction were cancelled and I got my BTC back.

Here you can see the note of blockchain.info: 
"Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: Transaction was previously accepted but has been pruned from our database."

The transaction were automatically resented, here is the id:
https://blockchain.info/tx/2362971d010c0d38e51019139a4ebee899d0861af3d5288fae6494bad5ecd3d2

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10986/5406

Answer (score 1):

this tx has "dust" output of 300 satoshi. miner nodes treat such transactions as non-standard and do not confirm them

> Could anyone say what happens to my transaction (~100 USD) if no miner
>   confirms it for some reason?

nothing happens to your transaction

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert in Block Chain but I read that nowadays Bitcoin is facing a problem with scaleability, so probably your transaction is a certain block and this block was not mined yet due to high numbers of transactions. I may be wrong but this is definitely a possibility.