# Why do transactions take so long to confirm in testnet?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, testnet, confirmations

I have created a transaction with high miner's fee and it is now in mempool (in testnet):

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/abcc4ce473f490896e87102fe3ffb857ff735a0fc97525dadf9c5b0ed5410f9f/

However, it doesn't seem to be confirming. It's already missed two opportunities to confirm. Transactions with much lower miner's fees are going through instead.

Is Bitcoin this random or am I missing something?

Comment: Another possible cause is that your transaction has an output which is [dust](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10986/what-is-meant-by-bitcoin-dust), as do several of its ancestors (which are also still unconfirmed).  But I am not sure whether the dust rule is enforced by testnet nodes by default.

Comment: It's confirmed now.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding your transaction shows an output:

```
"vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_RETURN 68656c6c6f5f776f726c64",
        "hex": "6a0b68656c6c6f5f776f726c64",
        "type": "nulldata"
      }
    }, ...
```

This might be the reason the miners won't touch it as it may be flagged as non-standard on older nodes. Notice the warning on blockcypher:

[image: Non-standard]

Maybe someone can comment on exactly why, as these null_data transactions were made standard on Bitcoin-core `0.9.0`, see https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#null-data

Comment: I wondered about this possibility, but I thought the "standard" checks were disabled on testnet.  Also, what with the segwit soft fork, I don't think there could possibly be any miners running 0.9.0 or earlier.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking as well, it's curious. blockcypher states it is in 71 mempools at the moment, seems low to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having problems with testnet which I have not seen before.  I'm thinking I may have changed something in my scripts but cannot see what it could be.  I'm using multi-sigs for most of the destination addresses

https://tchain.btc.com/2N16FGLa4YpTnCuby9xZT2T2q3rkAxfcX6Y
https://tchain.btc.com/5cd81ee81ca48500edb78956aefa6f9f06074a7a7a234579313e5e40cb01b022