# Can the minimum transaction with bitcoin (satochi) be updated to even less?

Tags: blockchain, math

Or is it not changeable by design ?

Comment: Hey RoboxFuze, do you mean a minimum value for recipient outputs or fees?

Comment: I think (because he mentions satoshis), he assumes that the minimum transaction is 1 satoshi and if it is possible to transfer less than 1 satoshi (or possible to change that minimum).

Comment: That's right Nathanael, you got it. Is it possible to change that minimum ?

Comment: yes Murrch, a minimum value for recipient output. Can it be less than 1 satoshi ? I understand Mr. Satochi set it this way. The question is : can Mr. Satochi update that mimimum at will ? Or is it not possible, by design, so that even Mr. Satochi cannot update this, should, even he, want to ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How was the dust limit of 546 satoshis was chosen? Why not 550 satoshis?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/86068/how-was-the-dust-limit-of-546-satoshis-was-chosen-why-not-550-satoshis)