# What criteria does bitcoin core use to set the dust flag

Tags: bitcoin-core, dust

If you are using coin control features in Bitcoin Core, and you select certain coins, the Dust alert will show up as either a yes or no.  What criteria is used to detect dust when the cost of sending small amounts changes over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a related Q and A here: [How was the dust limit of 546 satoshis was chosen? Why not 550 satoshis?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/86068/how-was-the-dust-limit-of-546-satoshis-was-chosen-why-not-550-satoshis)