# Enable dustRelayFee behavior on testnet to get error code 64: dust

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, testnet

Crafting and sending an utxo of 1 satoshi does works and get mined on testnet without error. 
However on mainnet the error `code 64: dust` arise.

I understand the basic idea that you are not able to broadcast a transaction containing an utxo with a value so low that spending it(the low utxo) would not be enough to pay its tx fees. [What is meant by Bitcoin dust?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10986/what-is-meant-by-bitcoin-dust/63405#63405)

So naturally I'm looking for setting this behavior in testnet in order to implement a proper way to handle this case. To do so I start my testnet node with:

> bitcoind -datadir=/Volumes/EXT_SD/bitcoin -dustrelayfee=0.00003

I don't understand why it still allow me to send an utxo of 1 satoshi [1 sat ex](https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/a8f597a1d4aed8681be6d9a4c7c8b786481aea01130041e95245779355035e47) as I expected to received an error `code 64: dust` instead of a successfull broadcast. The params `dustrelayfee` in the command line seems like recognised as the node start but looks like not working as I don't get an error when pushing a tx with an utxo of only 1 satoshi. 
 -> My goal is to have a testnet node which throw me an error related to dust output as testnet would do if a legacy output is below [546 satoshi](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/210354003-What-is-the-minimum-amount-I-can-send-)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You've already figured out how to change the dust limit and it works on testnet, so what do you want to do?

Comment: I edited my question and hope to be more clear, sorry for my misleading question.