# Can a receive transaction be 0 in a bitcoind’s rpc call listsinceblock transaction returned json?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, json-rpc, deposit

Suppose that I want to check all the valid deposits of the results of bitcoind’s rpc call listsinceblock transactions, can I found a ‘receive’ transactions with ‘amount’ as 0? Should I consider that as a valid deposit?

https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listsinceblock.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating zero value UTXOs would be an attack, attempting to clog Bitoin nodes.

See

- [What is meant by Bitcoin dust?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10986/13866)
- [Questions about dust](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=Dust)

Comment: ok thank you! Is there a minimum amount of bitcoin that should considered as valid (non attack)? I mean, if I have 1 E-10, can I consider it valid? And how much decimal can have?

Comment: I have added a link to my answer which explains the lower limit

Comment: oh, fine! Another question: is it true to consider just "receive" transactions to check only deposits?

Comment: Hi, please use the [Ask Question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at top of page to ask a new question.

Comment: done; https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113647/consider-only-deposits-in-a-bitcoind-s-rpc-call-listsinceblock-transaction-retur

Comment: Actually I don’t understand which relayfee I have to consider to calculate Dust. It seems that there is not a standard value

Comment: Different nodes can set different values. The effect is that some nodes might relay a small unconfirmed transaction and others might not. If enough nodes will relay it, it might reach a miner, the miner might include it in a block that all nodes would then accept.

Comment: Then, if a transaction is close to 0, but have more than 6 confirms, do I need to consider it?

Comment: You must choose the level of risk you are comfortable with. For very small value transactions that might be 0 (high risk) for buying a house that might be 6 (low risk)

Comment: ok thank you. For example now I'm managing a list of testnet/regtest transactions, because address start with "2" and "m" I think I could say this. In this case, I also need to avoid dust transactions?

Comment: Maybe take the [tour]? Note what it says about the purpose of comments.

Comment: but of course I'm asking clarification about your answer! I would like to clarify if dust need to be considered also for testnet transactions