# Consider only deposits in a bitcoind’s RPC call listsinceblock transaction returned JSON

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, json-rpc, deposit

I have a JSON result of a bitcoind’s RPC call `listsinceblock`. There are 4 categories of transaction:

- "send" means transactions sent
- "receive" means non-coinbase transactions received
- "generate" means coinbase transactions received with more than 100 confirmations
- "immature" means coinbase transactions received with 100 or fewer confirmations
- "orphan" means orphaned coinbase transactions received

As valid deposits, have I to consider just the "receive" category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're mining (yourself, not via a pool), you will never see categories "generate", "immature", or "orphan".

"send" is only for transactions you create yourself.

So yes, for incoming payments you should only look at the "receive" category.

It may be easier to use the `getreceivedbyaddress` RPC.