# walletcreatefundedpsbt declined with "Transaction amount too small" but the input is definitely not dust

Tags: api, dust

I am trying to `walletcreatefundedpsbt` for the amount of (roughly) `0.00045 BTC`, which is around $30 USD right now on 7 Mar 2024, and definitely does not look like dust. But I'm getting `"Transaction amount too small"` error in response.

The Bitcoin Core source code that I found that mentions this error is the following:

[image: bitcoin source code that generates the error]

The outputs in the transaction are (amounts redacted slightly for anonymity):

- below   0.0000046
- below   0.0000023
- below   0.00047

What is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> below 0.0000023

The dust limit applies to *each output* of a transaction including potential change outputs. The 230 sat output is below the [dust limit](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10986/5406).