# Is it even possible to spend a stash of 1-sat UTXOs?

Tags: transaction-fees, terminology, utxo-management

In terms of UTXO management, I have the following extreme example to illustrate my question. Let's say I have 1 BTC with 100 million UTXOs of 1 sat each (or even 10 million UTXOs with 10 sats each). My question is - is the entire 1 BTC balance unspendable in a higher fee environment OR is it spendable and I will just pay a high fee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *economically unspendable*. If you only had the described 1-sat UTXOs, you would be unable to build a transaction that meets the minimum feerate.

Each UTXO requires some blockspace to be spent. If this blockspace costs more in fees at a given feerate than the UTXO is worth, an input spending the UTXO negatively contributes to the fees of a transaction—the input cannot carry its own weight, other inputs would need to add more fees to cover the deficit. I describe such UTXOs as having a *negative effective value (at the given feerate)*.

As in your example, a UTXO might have a negative effective value even at the minimum feerate. I call such UTXOs *economically unspendable*. They can be spent, though only if the user deliberately pays extra for removing them from the UTXO set.

---

<sup>Note that the above terms differ from *[dust](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/41082/5406)*: the dust limit refers to the fixed amount of fees an input and output of a specific output type would cost at the discard feerate (3 ṩ/vB). The limit that makes an output *economically unspendable* is based on the cost of the input at the minimum feerate, and having a *negative effective value* is a property depending on the context of a given feerate.</sup>